# How to use values from Formik initial values and pass them back into React Select?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, formik, react-select

I've currently implemented a means of setting my Formik initial values from an API call which is all working fine but I'm currently facing an issue with re-populating my `react-select` field from my initial values.

At the moment, my initial values (snippet) from API fetch call looks like this:

```
const emptyGroup = {
       groupName: "",
       groupValues: []
}

const INITIAL_FORM_STATE = {
  myName: '',
  allGroups: [emptyGroup]
};

"allGroups": [
    {
      "groupName": "Group Astro",
      "groupValues": [
           {
             "value": "My Group A",
             "label": "My Group A"
           },
           {
             "value": "My Group B",
             "label": "My Group B"
           }
      ]
    }
]
```

Below is my react-select component:

```
<ReactSelect
   options={ myGroupOptions }   
   isMulti={true}
   name={`allGroups.${index}.groupValues`}
   onChange={(option) => formikProps.setFieldValue({`allGroups.${index}.groupValues`}, option.value)}
   onBlur={formikProps.handleBlur}
   value={ ????? }
 />
```

What I am unsure is, how do I feed the values from the `groupValues` array above back into `value={ ?????? }` so that when this `<ReactSelect />` component is rendered, it displays the values: `My Group A` `My Group B` within it?

Comment: Could you create a minimal reproducible issue in sandbox? Here -> https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: Well, you need to update the state in `formik` which in turn will update the state in your react-select, since `formik` contains all of your form values.

Comment: @PrateekThapa - `formik` state is all setup correctly but inorder for react-select to pick-up `groupValues`, I need to retrieve this into `value` which is the part I am unsure to do. Do I need to run some type of array processing against the value?

Comment: @PrateekThapa - managed to solve my issue as per my answer below

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone else comes across this issue/query, I managed to solve the issue as follows for `value` together with formik values:

```
<ReactSelect
   options={ myGroupOptions }   
   isMulti={true}
   name={`allGroups.${index}.groupValues`}
   onChange={(option) => formikProps.setFieldValue({`allGroups.${index}.groupValues`}, option.value)}
   onBlur={formikProps.handleBlur}
   value={values.allGroups[index].groupValues}
 />
```